# What type of replication can be used with Oracle Database 11g R2 Standard Edition One?

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle11g

My organization plans to buy two servers with two Oracle 11g R2 SE1 licenses. It is need to set up bidirectional replication between servers' databases (both databases are fully identical in DB structure and practically identical in data except table with server-specific data (application parameters values, such as server ID and so on).

I think about Advanced replication (multimaster), is this match with the 11g R2 SE1 license?
Is there any other Oracle solution, suitable for my circumstances and the 11g R2 SE1 license?
Or, in other case, what third-party Oracle replication engine you can advise?

Thanks.

Comment: I know that MySQL would be acceptable in this case and some more cheaper than Oracle, but it isn't my desision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Oracle 11.2 Licensing Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e10594/editions.htm#BABDJGGI), it appears that Streams is available in SE1.  That is Oracle's preferred technology for bidirectional data replication.  There are some limitations of Streams in SE1-- it appears, for example, that you are limited to [synchronous capture](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28324/tdpii_repcont.htm#BABDEBBA) based on My Oracle Support document 567872.1.

Comment: By the way, synchronous capture is not suitable for replicating lots of frequently updated tables, which is typical for OLTP systems. It will generate a lot of overhead on the source DB.

Comment: As I understand there are two replication approaches with Oracle standard edition - Basic replication using materialized views and Oracle Streams. Any guidance on what are the pros and cons of each if there are no frequent data updates between primary and secondary servers?